# Location change for Logs in play framework

Tags: java, apache, logging, playframework

I have been newly working on Play framework and the version is 1.2.5. The logs for my application are stored at location where the entire application is installed. I have installed my application package in C:\app location and running it through Java wrapper.

I am confused as my log.properties file do not say anything about the stored location of log, as shown below, but still it is logging in default log folder of play.

Below is the exactly copied log.properties file for my application which is working fine. Few lines are commented but that is how I have received it.

```
#properties file used for log4j
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, Console

log4j.logger.play=DEBUG

# Rolling files
#log4j.appender.Rolling=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.Rolling.File=logs/application.log
#log4j.appender.Rolling.MaxFileSize=1MB
#log4j.appender.Rolling.MaxBackupIndex=100
#log4j.appender.Rolling.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.Rolling.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{DATE} %-5p ~ %m%n


# Console
log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p ~ %m%n
```

All I want to know is how Play is storing it there, Is there any class of Play that has this location stored, and How can I configure to change the location of building logs to other drive say `E:\logs`?

Answer (score 0):

It is responsible for the location of the log folder,

```
#log4j.appender.Rolling.File=logs/application.log
```

will generate logs in the application path with a folder `logs`

you can change it to the desired location `E:\logs` in the above line to generate logs in the `E:`

You will find the default settings of logging,

```
# Logger
# ~~~~~
```

section in `application.conf` inside your `/conf` directory of your play app.

Comment: @ San Krish : This is what I too figured out but as we can see Line is commented ,so how can it be responsible for any action

Comment: It might be with the default location unless you override. that is the reason you get the logs generated even the line is commented

Comment: In that case, can you please suggest where to look for such default configuration in Play. I mean any Class or possibly any file in play directory.?

Comment: i am not sure . you can check in `application.conf` in the conf folder

Comment: Well, i have already tried that..This is all conf file syas

# Log level
# ~~~~~
# Specify log level for your application.
# If you want a very customized log, create a log4j.properties file in the conf directory
 application.log=DEBUG
#
# More logging configuration
  application.log.path=/log4j.properties
# application.log.system.out=off

Comment: Also changing the location as suggested by you...didn't work out. I changed 
`#log4j.appender.Rolling.File=logs/application.log`
to
`log4j.appender.Rolling.File=E:/logs`
 but no use..

Comment: where have you placed the `log4j.xml` file ?

Comment: I am not using log4j.xml I have a log4j.properties(text) file instead and that I have placed in the /conf folder of play structure